# How do I get my asynchronous fetch function to update my component when I need it to?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm implementing a feature in my React thesaurus application that finds all of the permutations of a given word, and then makes a fetch request to a dictionary API that I'm using in the rest of my application for each of the permutations and renders them in a list, if data is returned (indicating a valid word).

The feature works, but not as I hoped. Each render is one step behind. For example, if I start the application and search for the word 'care', nothing will show up in my list of anagrams. However, on my next search, all of the anagrams for the word 'care' do appear.

I'm not tremendously experienced with the oddities of asynchronous behavior and I'm relatively new to learning React, so please forgive any blatantly obvious mistakes here.

This is my code:

```
const Anagrams = () => {
// The following context is the user input that is handled throughout the rest of my application
const { wordContext, setWordContext } = useWordContext();

/* The currAnagrams slice of state is used to hold all of my permutations that are found
   by my function below */
const [currAnagrams, setCurrAnagrams] = useState([]);
/* The validAnagrams slice of state is used to hold all of the valid anagrams that
   are found by my fetch call */
const [validAnagrams, setValidAnagrams] = useState([]);
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
const [srcIndex, setSrcIndex] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    /* I've omitted all of the code inside of this useEffect as it is
       irrelevant to the problem at hand. The permutations(function) merely
       finds all of the permutations of the given input (wordContext) */

     if (wordContext.length < 6) {
        permutations(wordContext);
        setCurrAnagrams(myAnagrams);
    };
}, [wordContext]);

useEffect(() => {
    /* This is where things get dicey. I am looping through my array of permutations,
       making a fetch request for each value, and pushing it into the finalAnagrams
       array. I am monitoring wordContext (as I do in the rest of my application)
       so that when a new word is searched, the function will run and all of the valid
       anagrams will be set to their designated slice of state */

    const finalAnagrams = [];
    
    const fetchAnagrams = async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < currAnagrams.length; i++) {
            const fetchRequest = await fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${currAnagrams[i]}`);

            const fetchJSON = await fetchRequest.json();

            if (!fetchJSON.title) finalAnagrams.push(fetchJSON[0].word)
        };
    };

    fetchAnagrams();
    setValidAnagrams(finalAnagrams);
}, [wordContext]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (srcIndex === 2) setSrcIndex(0);
}, [srcIndex]);

useEffect(() => {
    setClicked(false);
    setSrcIndex(0);
}, [wordContext]);

// This is where my valid anagrams are finally mapped through and rendered as links
const showResults = validAnagrams.sort().map((anagram, i) => <Link 
    to={`/${anagram}`} 
    className='anagram-li' 
    key={i}
    onClick={() => setWordContext(anagram)}>{anagram}</Link>);

return (
    <div>

        {
            wordContext.length < 6 ?
            <div id='anagram-results'>
                <p className='header'>Anagrams:</p>
                <button 
                id='expand-anagrams' 
                style={{backgroundImage: imgArr[srcIndex]}} 
                onClick={() => {
                setClicked((isClicked) => !isClicked)
                setSrcIndex(srcIndex + 1)}}>
            </button>
            </div> :
            <p id='no-anagrams'>No anagrams to show here!</p>
        }

        {
            clicked && 
            showResults
        }

    </div>
  );
};
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking the `wordContext` value before and after context value is changed? You can use `React Dev Tools` or simply `console.log` to check the context value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try moving the set call inside the async function ?.

```
const finalAnagrams = [];

const fetchAnagrams = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < currAnagrams.length; i++) {
        const fetchRequest = await fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${currAnagrams[i]}`);

        const fetchJSON = await fetchRequest.json();

        if (!fetchJSON.title) finalAnagrams.push(fetchJSON[0].word)
    };
setValidAnagrams(finalAnagrams);
};

fetchAnagrams();
```

I hope it helps!!

Thanks,
Anu.